# Form Submit using Angularjs to SpringMVC Controller using $http.post

Tags: angularjs, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

How to send multiple data  from jsp to Springmvc controller to change password.
I wants to change password using angular js.
How to solve this?

Alert message showing properly but cannot call controller using post method.

My js code

```
myangu.controller('account', function($scope, $http) {

    var submitvalue = $scope.detailspassword = function() {

        alert($scope.confirmpassword + "" + $scope.newpassword + ""
                + $scope.existedpassword);

    };
    var submitvalue = function(request) {

    };
    var error = function(reason) {
        alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({
            reason : reason
        }));

        $scope.errormessage = "Something Wrong.Cannot Change Your Password";

    };

    $http.post('/java/updatepassword').then(submitvalue, error);

});
```

SpringMvc controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatepassword", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String updatepassword(@RequestBody Users users) throws JSONException,NullPointerException,JsonGenerationException{

        System.out.println("Updatedpassword"+users.getPassword());


        return uservice.updatepassword(users);
    }
```

Jsp page

```
<div class="divTablebody">
    <div  ng-controller="account">
        <%-- <form:form action="/java/changepassword"  method="POST" > --%>
        <div>{{errormessage}}</div>
        <div class="divTableRow">


            <div class="divTableCell">Existed password:</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Existed Password"
                    id="Existedpw" ng-model="existedpassword">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">New password:</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <input type="password" placeholder="New Password" id="newpw"
                    ng-model="newpassword">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">Password Confirmation:</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password "
                    id="confirmpw" ng-model="confirmpassword">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">Save</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <input type="submit" id="pwsubmit" ng-click="detailspassword()" name="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data in post call as second parameter.

```
var objPassword = {
       existedpassword : $scope.existedpassword
       newpassword : $scope.newpassword
       newpassword : $scope.confirmpassword
}

$http.post('/java/updatepassword',objPassword).then(submitvalue, error);
```

For more [Angular#POST](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

EDIT :

```
myangu.controller('account', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.detailspassword = function () {
        alert($scope.confirmpassword + "" + $scope.newpassword + "" + $scope.existedpassword);
        var formData = { cpass: $scope.confirmpassword, newpass: $scope.newpassword, oldpass: $scope.existedpassword };

        var error = function (responce) {
            $scope.errormessage = "Unsuccessful";
        };
        $http.post('/java/updatepassword',formData).then(submitvalue, error);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: myangu.controller('account', [
  '$scope',
  '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {

  

   $scope.detailspassword = function() {

    alert($scope.confirmpassword + "" + $scope.newpassword + ""
      + $scope.existedpassword);
    var formData = {
     cpass : $scope.confirmpassword,
     newpass : $scope.newpassword,
     oldpass : $scope.existedpassword
    };
    
    var error=function(responce){
      
     $scope.errormessage="Unsuccessful";
      
    };
                
    $http.post('/java/updatepassword').then(formData, error);};
  } ]); not working @Ritchie

Comment: Please check your comment in EDIT

Comment: Check in console of browser

Comment: It  working and got value in Controller but in jsp showing error message.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this scenario is: a user logged in and is going to change the password

how about try this, 
modify your backend by receiving the old password, new password and userId from `@RequestParams` (or if you don't have userId then use whatever that are unique for each user like email to query user's information from your DB)

in Spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatepassword", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody String updatepassword(@RequestParam String userId, @RequestParam String existedPassword, @RequestParam String newPassword) {

    // query user by userId and match if existedPassword from request param is the same as user.getPassword()
   // if password is correct then update the password to the new password and 
   // return blabla


}
```

then take a look at controller in angular

```
// first check if $scope.newpassword is the same value as $scope.confirmpassword 
// then send the following POST request

$http.post('/java/updatepassword', 
  { params: { 
       "userId": userId,          // as long as, the user logged in so you can get userId somehow
       "existedPassword": $scope.existedpassword, 
       "newPassword": $scope.newpassword
            }
  })
.then(function successCallback(response) {
   // success
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Hope it can help you get alternative way to solve this :)